# jquery if else for starters

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm quite new to js and jquery, and I find that jquery-starters all run into the same if else problem. How much I search on other sites or here, the examples are to complicated at this point ;) Can anyone help me with this very basic statement, would mean a lot...

The problem: I want to hide a button after 4 clicks. I'm using a variable to count the clicks, but the result is that the button is hidden after 1 click, not 4. Anyone?

```html
<script> 
  
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    var x = 0;
    
    $(".but_mirror_right").click(function(){
        $("#spiegel_links").animate({left:'+=200%'}, 6000);
        
  x += 1;
  alert(x);
     
  if (x = 4) {
   $("#but_right").hide();
  }
  else {
   $("#but_right").show(); 
  } 
 });
});
  
</script>
```

Comment: `=` is to *set* a value. Use `==` to *check* a value, eg `if (x == 4)`. You could also use `===` if you want to do a check on the values without any type coercion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
if (x = 4) {
```

to

```
if (x == 4) {
```

or

```
if (x === 4) {
```

`=` is an assignment operator and the statement `x = 4` will always return true, that is why the code is not working as expected. You should replace it with `==` or `===`

Comment: Hi Raghubendra, thats it, you've just become my personal hero!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
if (x = 4) {
```

to this

```
if (x === 4) {
```

The first one assigns 4 to `x`, which always evaluates to true, so that branch is always followed. The second tests equality.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x = 4)
```

Should be

```
if (x === 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if(x=4)` to `(x==4)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var x = 0;
  $(".but_mirror_right").click(function() {
   // $("#spiegel_links").animate({
   //   left: '+=200%'
 //   }, 6000);
    x += 1;
    console.log(x);
    if (x == 4) {
      $("#but_right").hide();
    } else {
      $("#but_right").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="but_mirror_right">button</button>
<button id="but_right">toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var x = 0;
  $(".but_mirror_right").click(function() {
    x ++;
    console.log(x);
    if (x >= 4) {
      $("#but_right").hide();
    } else {
      $("#but_right").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="but_mirror_right">button</button>
<button id="but_right">toggle</button>
<p>Button will disable after 4 click</p>
```

you are assining 4 to x. check for `'=' '==' '==='` operator